# How MySQL one to many and one to one relationships are defined?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I was referring these to Hibernate tuts: [1](https://www.journaldev.com/2924/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-annotation), [2](https://www.journaldev.com/2916/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-example-annotation).

I was not able to understand how one to one and one to many relationships are defined in MySQL tables.

This is SQL for one to many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE `Cart` (
  `cart_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `total` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cart_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `item_total` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cart_id` (`cart_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `Cart` (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is SQL for one to one relationship:

```
-- Create Transaction Table
CREATE TABLE `Transaction` (
  `txn_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txn_date` date NOT NULL,
  `txn_total` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`txn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create Customer table
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `txn_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cust_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cust_email` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`txn_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`txn_id`) REFERENCES `Transaction` (`txn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If eyes are ok, I dont see any difference between two. Is it like this relationship cardinality constraints are implemented only at hibernate level and are not enforced by database? Or my eyes are missing something?

Comment: Your `transaction` and `customer` entities are really strange.  Why don't you have a customer id somewhere?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am just referring to linked articles

Comment: @TheImpaler So basically there is nothing here and anywhere at SQL level to look for one to one mapping. So its only implemented in hibernate layer then...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to define 1:1 relationships in SQL. There are two ways:

1. The child table has the same PK as the parent table, with the same values. This column is also an FK to the parent table.
2. The child table has a different PK. It also has a FK that points to the parent table, and this FK has a UNIQUE constraint.

If you noticed, in both cases the FK is UNIQUE (it's the PK, or has a UNIQUE constraint), and that's the key aspect. It's not possible the create a second row in the child table that has the same parent.

The case you included in your question opted for strategy #1.